# A Curious Identity

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I met the following equations when I was trying to solve a complex line integral (W.Rudin, RCA, p.228 ex.13). My question is how to prove them:

We have to show that for $n>2$ even

$$
2^{n/2}\prod^{\left(n - 2\right)/2}_{k = 1}
\left[1 - \cos\left(2k\pi \over n\right)\right] = n,
$$

and for $n>1$ odd,

$$
2^{\left(n - 1\right)/2}\prod_{k = 1}^{\left(n - 1\right)/2}
\left[1 - \cos\left(2k\pi \over n\right)\right]
=n\text{ ?}$$

-This can be rewritten as a curious identity after the below hint of Greg Martin-

Thx.

Comment: Hint: $2(1-\cos x) = 2-e^{ix}-e^{-ix} = (1-e^{ix})(1-e^{-ix})$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70231/how-to-prove-those-curious-identities

Comment: For an elementary method, take a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650354/prove-trigonometric-relation/650668#650668)