# How to prove the following trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sum of the reciprocal of sine squared](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122836/sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-sine-squared)

Can anyone help me?

If $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{N}$, where $N\geqslant 2$

How to prove the following equation?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac1{\sin^2(k\alpha)}=\frac{N^2-1}{3}$$

Comment: Good eye, @Sam!