# Sum of fractions of squared sines

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I'm trying to prove the following approximate identity for $p$ integer:
$$
\sum_{l=1}^m\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi l}{p}\right)}{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi l}{mp}\right)}\sim \frac{m^2(p-1)}{2}+O(m)
$$

Things I have tried:

- Convert to an integral through a Riemann sum, however, the function $1/\sin^2(x)$ and it's derivatives are unbounded for small $x$
- I tried to relate it to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122836/sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-sine-squared), but I found it impossible to eliminate the numerator, simply averaging over one period of $p$ doesn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For large $m$, the quantity $\pi \ell/(m p)$ is small except where $\ell \approx m$.  Even then, the argument of the sine is small for even moderate values of $p$, so to first order we can replace the sine by its argument.  Thus the ratio looks like, approximately,

$$\left (\frac{m p}{\pi} \right )^2 \sum_{\ell=1}^m \frac{\sin^2{\frac{\pi \ell}{p}}}{\ell^2}$$

Now, you can evaluate the sum as $m \to \infty$ using the following relation, derived [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331404/how-to-prove-this-identity-pi-sum-limits-k-infty-infty-left-frac-sin/331407#331407):

$$\sum_{\ell=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2{a \ell}}{\ell^2} = \pi a$$

when $a \in [0,\pi)$.  Here, $a=\pi/p$, so we are OK.  Thus we have that the fraction is approximately

$$\frac12 \left (\frac{m p}{\pi} \right )^2 \left (\frac{\pi^2}{p}-\frac{\pi^2}{p^2} \right ) = \frac12 m^2 \left (p-1 \right )$$

**ADDENDUM**

You can also show that the next order term is $O(m)$ by considering the next term in the expansion of the sine in the denominator.  That is, we can easily show that, when the argument is "small":

$$\frac1{\sin^2{\frac{\pi \ell}{m p}}} \sim \left (\frac{m p}{\pi \ell} \right )^2 + \frac13$$

The first term gives the above result.  The second term may be evaluated exactly:

$$\frac13 \sum_{\ell=1}^m \sin^2{\frac{\pi \ell}{p}} = \frac1{12} \left [2 m+1 - \frac{\sin{\left ( (2 m+1) \frac{\pi}{p}\right )}}{\sin{\frac{\pi}{p}}} \right ] \sim \frac{m}{6}$$

for large $m$.  Thus the next order term is $O(m)$ as expected.

Comment: But doesn't that need a bit more arguing, as $\ell$ can take values up to $m$ — in which case the quantity $\frac{\ell}{m}$ is clearly not small enough to replace $\sin$ by its Taylor series?

Comment: @ClementC.: True.  But then the worst-case scenario is $p=2$ ($p=1$ gives an identically zero sum), in which we can say that it's just a numerically mediocre approximation which gets better for large $p$.

Comment: I agree --- just wanted to point out that this needed saying :) As a matter of fact, for $p\geq 2$ (since $p=1$ is trival as you mentioned), one can use the loose inequality $$x\leq \sin x \leq \frac{2}{\pi}x,\qquad x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$ to derive the result (*up to a constant multiplicative factor*), as one can apply the inequality to the denominator as long as $0\leq \ell\leq \frac{p}{2}m$, which is always true.

Comment: @ClementC.: I agree with that too.  Thank you for the edifying comments.

Comment: @ClementC.: Out of curiosity: the approximation seems to hold for arbitrary $p\geq 1$, with no integer restrictions. The case $p\geq 2$ follow from your answer. However, for $p$ close to 1 the denominator gets small for both $l\approx 1$ and $l\approx m$, with the Taylor expansion only small for $l\approx 1$. Any ideas on how to prove the approximation for all $p\geq 1$?

Comment: PS: the inequalities above were reversed (LateX typo): it should read $\frac{2}{\pi} x \leq \sin x \leq x$, where the upper bound holds no matter where $x$ lies and the lower bound only for $0\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I suppose one could try to prove something of the form 
$$ \alpha \frac{\sin\frac{\pi\ell}{x}}{\sin\frac{\pi\ell}{m x}} \leq \beta$$
for any fixed $x\in[1,2]$ and $\ell,m$; ($\alpha,\beta$ not depending on $\ell,m$). Or, equivalently,
$$ \alpha \frac{\sin\frac{\pi m r}{x}}{\sin\frac{\pi r}{x}} \leq \beta$$
for any fixed $x\in[1,2]$ and $r\in[\frac{1}{m}{1}],m\in\mathbb{N}$.
This seems to hold, in particular since intuitively the hard case should be the lower bound around $x=1$, and [the limit exists](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+sin%28pi+m+x%29%2Fsin%28pi+x%2Fy%29%29+at+y+%3D+1).