# Reference for a tangent squared sum identity

Tags: reference-request, trigonometry, summation

Can anyone help me find a formal reference for the following identity about the summation of squared tangent function:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^m\tan^2\frac{k\pi}{2m+1} = 2m^2+m,\quad m\in\mathbb{N}^+.
$$

I have proved it, however, the proof is too long to be included in a paper. So I just want to refer to some books or published articles.

I also found it to be a special case of the following identity,

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}\tan^2\frac{k\pi}{n} = \frac16(n-1)(-(-1)^n (n + 1) + 2 n - 1),\quad n\in\mathbb{N}^+
$$

which is provided by [Wolfram](http://functions.wolfram.com/01.08.23.0007.01).

Thank you very much!

Comment: I can't give you a reference but check this question out. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339/prove-that-sum-k-1n-1-tan2-frack-pi2n-fracn-12n-13?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Aleks, it is pretty good to find this proof. However I think I'd better find a reference for it.

Comment: It's similar to Proof 9 in [Robin Chapman's list of ways to evaluate $\zeta(2)$](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Jolley, Summation of Series, formula 445 is $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\tan^2\left(\theta+{k\pi\over n}\right)=n^2\cot^2\left({n\pi\over2}+n\theta\right)+n(n-1)$$ Let $\displaystyle\theta={\pi\over2m+1}$, $n=2m+1$ and we almost have your sum; we have twice your sum, since the angles here go from just over zero to just under $\pi$, while in your sum they go from just over zero to just under $\pi/2$, and $\tan^2\theta=\tan^2(\pi-\theta)$.

Jolley's reference is to page 73 of S L Loney, Plane Trigonometry, Cambridge University Press, 1900. This book is best known from its part in Ramanujan's early education.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this type of formula is related to binomial coefficients. I give a proof of the general case I found in my post [Tan binomial formulas from a set S and its k-subset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517630/tan-binomial-formulas-from-a-set-s-and-its-k-subsets)