# Trig sum: $\tan ^21^\circ+\tan ^22^\circ+\cdots+\tan^2 89^\circ = \text{?}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation

As the title suggests, I'm trying to find the sum $$\tan^21^\circ+\tan^2 2^\circ+\cdots+\tan^2 89^\circ$$
I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve complex numbers, or any other advanced branch in maths. The solution can involve techniques such as induction, telecoping, etc, but preferably only ideas from precalculus, e.g. trig identities, polynomials, etc.

EDIT: I know that the sum is a rational number.

Comment: Are you sure the sum is rational? How do you know?

Comment: But how would your calculator have given an irrational sum? [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum&a=*C.sum-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=tan+(k+pi+%2F+180)&f=Sum.sumfunction_tan+(k+pi+%2F+180)&f3=1&f=Sum.sumlowerlimit_1&f4=89&f=Sum.sumupperlimit2_89&a=*FVarOpt.1-_**-.***Sum.sumvariable---.*--) gives $265.0173714620087662428704848470169312673078166104585039010061...$, which looks fairly irrational to me, in this context.

Comment: I _converted_ to radians, for Wolfram Alpha's benefit. The sum is unchanged.

Comment: Well, one of us is going to look silly here. Let us know when you find your calculator.

Comment: That's better! Now we get $5310.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333...$. Now there's a rational number if ever I saw one.

Comment: Funnily enough, Wolfram Alpha doesn't get it. If you go [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum&a=*C.sum-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=tan%5E2+(k+pi+%2F+180)&f=Sum.sumfunction_tan%5E2+(k+pi+%2F+180)&f3=1&f=Sum.sumlowerlimit%5Cu005f1&f4=89&f=Sum.sumupperlimit2%5Cu005f89&a=*FVarOpt.1-_**-.***Sum.sumvariable---.*--) and click on "Exact form", you get a horrible mess instead of $15931/3$.

Comment: i get $\frac{15931}3$ with a calculator.

Comment: Most likely the $15931/3$ is an error. It may be a number *very close* to it but pocket calculators don't seem to differentiate. WA would pick up something like this and it didn't. Usually a good indicator that this is a coincidence.

Comment: One thing to try: instead of doing the "special" case where you're looking at degrees, can you find a formula for $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \tan^2 {k \pi \over 2n}$, where the angles are in radians?  Your question is the $n = 90$ case of this.  If you try small integer values of $n$ it's not terribly hard to conjecture a formula.

Comment: Also, possibly relevant SE links: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217240/reference-for-a-tangent-squared-sum-identity, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339/prove-that-sum-k-1n-1-tan2-frack-pi2n-fracn-12n-13?rq=1 , although I'm not sure if any of the proofs here satisfy your requirements - this problem seems very naturally to live in the complex numbers.

Comment: @Alitzer: Try this then: instead of clicking on "Exact form" in my link ([here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum&a=%2AC.sum-_%2ACalculator.dflt-&f2=tan%5E2+(k+pi+%2F+180)&f=Sum.sumfunction_tan%5E2+(k+pi+%2F+180)&f3=1&f=Sum.sumlowerlimit%5Cu005f1&f4=89&f=Sum.sumupperlimit2%5Cu005f89&a=%2AFVarOpt.1-_%2A%2A-.%2A%2A%2ASum.sumvariable---.%2A--)), click on "More digits" until you get bored. Do you still think it's irrational? I'm not claiming a proof, but it does suggest that your faith in WA might be misplaced.

Comment: $15931 = 89 \times 179$, by the way.

Comment: The 89 pairs of numbers $\pm \tan 1^\circ, \pm \tan 2^\circ, \ldots, \pm \tan 89^\circ$
are the roots of the polynomial
$$\frac{(1+it)^{180} - (1-it)^{180}}{2i^{179}t} = \binom{180}{1} t^{178} - \binom{180}{3} t^{176} + \cdots$$
Even though the LHS of this formula include complex number, the RHS didn't. If you can justify the RHS, then you are done.

Comment: @achillehui, Did you mean the following ?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee  yes (even though I derive the formula by other mean).

Comment: See this for an easier method https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3739719/545151

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From 
[Sum of tangent functions where arguments are in specific arithmetic series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346368/sum-of-tangent-functions-where-arguments-are-in-specific-arithmetic-series),

$$\tan180x=\frac{\binom{180}1t-\binom{180}3t^3+\cdots+\binom{180}{177}t^{177}-\binom{180}{179}t^{179}}{1-\binom{180}2t^2+\cdots-\binom{180}{178}t^{178}+\binom{180}{180}t^{180}}$$ where $t=\tan x$

If we set $\tan180x=0,180x=180^\circ r$ where $r$ is any integer

$\implies x=r^\circ$ where $0\le r<180$

So, the roots of $\binom{180}1t-\binom{180}3t^3+\cdots+\binom{180}{177}t^{177}-\binom{180}{179}t^{179}=0$
$\iff\binom{180}{179}t^{179}-\binom{180}{177}t^{177}+\cdots+\binom{180}3t^3-\binom{180}1t=0$ are $\tan r^\circ$  where $0\le r<180,r\ne90$ ($r=90$ corresponds to the denominator $=\infty$)

So, the roots of $\binom{180}{179}t^{178}-\binom{180}{177}t^{176}+\cdots+\binom{180}3t^2-\binom{180}1=0$ are $\tan r^\circ$  where $0<r<180,r\ne90$

So, the roots of $\binom{180}{179}u^{89}-\binom{180}{177}u^{88}+\cdots+\binom{180}3u-\binom{180}1=0$ are $\tan^2r^\circ$  where $0<r<90$

Using Vieta's formula, $\sum_{r=1}^{89}\tan^2r^\circ=\dfrac{\binom{180}{177}}{\binom{180}{179}}$

Comment: To add on to your beautiful answer, the solution can be rewritten somewhat more tangibly as: $$\dfrac{\frac{180\cdot 179\cdot 178}{6}}{\frac{180}{1}} = \frac{15931}{3}.$$

Comment: @CameronWilliams, I actually left it for the user:)

Comment: My apologies. Guess I'll delete it then.

Comment: @AnalysisIncarnate, I've a predilection for this method. Thanks for relating the two.

Answer (score 20):

The function
$$
\frac{180/z}{z^{180}-1}
$$
has residue $1$ at each root of $z^{180}-1$ $\left(\text{i.e. }e^{k\pi i/90}\text{ for }k=0\dots179\right)$ and residue $-180$ at $z=0$.

On $|z|=1$,
$$
\tan(\theta/2)=-i\frac{z-1}{z+1}
$$
Integrating
$$
f(z)=-\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^2\frac{180/z}{z^{180}-1}
$$
around a large circle is $0$ since the integrand is approximately $|z|^{-181}$. Thus, the sum of residues is
$$
2\sum_{k=0}^{89}\tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{180}\right)+\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}f(z)+\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-1}f(z)=0
$$
Since $\operatorname*{Res}\limits_{z=0}f(z)=180$ and $\operatorname*{Res}
\limits_{z=-1}f(z)=-\frac{32402}{3}$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{89}\tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{180}\right)
&=\frac12\left(\frac{32402}{3}-180\right)\\
&=\frac{15931}{3}
\end{align}
$$

---

This same method also gives
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{89}\tan^4\left(\frac{k\pi}{180}\right)=\frac{524560037}{45}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{89}\tan^6\left(\frac{k\pi}{180}\right)=\frac{4855740968543}{135}
$$

Comment: Ah, I just saw the part of the question that mentions no complex methods. I will leave this, anyway, as a comparison. $\dfrac{n/z}{z^n-1}$ is a useful function to evaluate sums on $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I've found this excellent answer via an answer to my question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877014/a-series-involving-csc4/1877743#1877743 -- handy trick, thanks! However, it seems this works only since $z\mapsto\tan(\arg z)$ is analytic (outside of its poles), which doesn't generalize to other sums, for instance involving $\sin$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @heiner: $\sin(\theta)=\frac1{2i}\left(z-\frac1z\right)$ on the unit circle, so you could use that.

Answer (score 1):

The following function
$$r_m(x)=\frac{(1+ix)^m-(1-ix)^m}{(1+ix)^m+(1-ix)^m}$$
has the easy property
$$r_m(\tan\theta)=i\tan(m\theta).$$
If we set $r_{180}(x)=0$, cancelling $x$, we find lab's equation again:
$$180x^{178}-{180\choose 3}x^{176}+...=0$$
with roots $\small\tan1^\circ,...,\tan89^\circ,\tan91^\circ,...,\tan179^\circ$. Setting $x^2=t$ and Vieta's formula concludes.