# trigonometric finite series equals to polynomial function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, trigonometric-series, sums-of-squares

I am interest to prove the equation below :
$$
\sum_{k=1}^m  \tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m+1}\right) =  m(2m+1) 
$$
you can understand better the first member of the equation here:

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+1+to+m++tan%28k*pi%2F%282*m%2B1%29%29%5E2)

(mark the whole url with your mouse because i dont know why the link isn't blue at all)
sorry but i am not familiar writing equations here .
i hope to understand. 
so what's the problem in formula i cannot eliminate the trigonometric functions to prove this series is a polynomial .
any idea how to manipulate the formula ?

Comment: Hmm... I do not think this correct. You have entered wrong indeces in W|A . 

May a give you a tip? We don't usually write the multiplication symbol in algebraic manipulations, unless necessary. For example , you write $2\pi $ not $2 \cdot \pi$ but you DO write $2\cdot 3 \cdot 4$ in order not to confuse this with the number $234$ (two hundred and thirty four).

Comment: @Tolaso Can you elaborate on why you think it's wrong.  I tried a few $m$-values and the formula checked out.

Comment: Then there must a problem with the indeces. I do not get. The summation is over $k$? And that $n$ at the denominator? 

@Chaviaras michalis Could you clarify what the summation is over ? Because at W|A link there is no specific place. W|A takes it over $m$.

Comment: @Tolaso I just changed the index of summation back to $k$ and changed the denominator in the tangent, the sum is over $k$, not $m$ (since $m$ appears on the RHS).

Comment: Ok. Thanks! Well, with a quick check (using W|A) the sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{100} \tan^2 (k\pi/(200+1))$$

is equal to $20100$ which is correct. So, it is true.  So, all that remains is a proof. And I guess that it will telescope. But until I search it , I cannot be sure.

Comment: Very similar : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339/prove-that-sum-k-1n-1-tan2-frack-pi2n-fracn-12n-13?lq=1                                           And in here is the exact same: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173447/proving-sum-limits-l-1n-sum-limits-k-1n-1-tan-frac-lk-pi-2n1-t/173649#173649

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311717) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is a nearly identical copy of falagar's beautiful answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339/prove-that-sum-k-1n-1-tan2-frack-pi2n-fracn-12n-13?lq=1), all credit goes to him.

---

For the sake of legibility let $x_k:=\tfrac{k\pi}{2m+1}$ for $k=1,\ldots,m$. By [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) we have the identity
$$(\cos x_k+i\sin x_k)^{2m+1}=(-1)^k,$$
for each $k$. The binomial expansion of the left hand side gives us
$$\sum_{j=0}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}{j}(i\sin x_k)^j(\cos x_k)^{2m+1-j}=(-1)^k.$$
Taking the imaginary parts of both sides shows that the terms with odd $j$ sum to zero:
$$\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{2m+1}{2j+1}(-1)^j(\sin x_k)^{2j+1}(\cos x_k)^{2m-2j}=0.$$
Dividing both sides by $(\sin x_k)(\cos x_k)^{2m}$ we find that
$$\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{2m+1}{2j+1}(-1)^j(\tan x_k)^{2j}=\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{2m+1}{2j+1}\left(-(\tan x_k)^2\right)^j=0,$$
This means that $-(\tan x_k)^2$ is a root of the polynomial
$$\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{2m+1}{2j+1}X^j=0,$$
for $k=1,\ldots,m$, and the values of $-(\tan x_k)^2$ are distinct for distinct values of $k$. Hence these are all roots of the polynomial above, and by [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) its roots sum to
$$-\frac{\tbinom{2m+1}{2m-1}}{\tbinom{2m+1}{2m+1}}=-\binom{2m+1}{2m-1}=-m(2m+1).$$