# How to find the equations whose roots are equal to the following numbers?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

How to find the equations whose roots are equal to the following numbers ?

(a) $\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2n+1}$,$\sin^2\frac{2\pi}{2n+1}$,$\sin^2\frac{3\pi}{2n+1}$,...,$\sin^2\frac{n\pi}{2n+1}$

(b)$\cot^2\frac{\pi}{2n+1}$,$\cot^2\frac{2\pi}{2n+1}$,$\cot^2\frac{3\pi}{2n+1}$,...,$\cot^2\frac{n\pi}{2n+1}$

I got stuck while solving this problem.This was from a complex number chapter practice problem exercise. I tried to fit in Demoivre's theorem considering roots of unity.But no idea how to bring about the squared sine terms.  Any suggestions?

Comment: neglecting this solution $$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(x-\sin^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Did'nt get you @Chinny84

Comment: since I know that an equation with roots $a_0,a_1$ and $a_2$ can be given by $$(x-a_0)(x-a_1)(x-a_2)=\prod_{i=0}^2\left(x-a_i\right)$$. This is just a "trivial" solution.

Comment: Isnt that a bit too trivial :/

Comment: yup, thats why I said neglecting this solution ;).

Comment: Maybe a more constructive comment would be to know that $$\sin^2 x = \frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$$ thus you are look for roots, $r_k$ of the form $$r_k = \frac{1-\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{2n+1}\right)}{2}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $(b),$ see [Trig sum: $\tan ^21^\circ+\tan ^22^\circ+...+\tan^2 89^\circ = ?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951522/trig-sum-tan-21-circ-tan-22-circ-tan2-89-circ)

For $(a),$

**Method** $\#1:$ $$\cot^2y=\dfrac{1-\sin^2y}{\sin^2y}$$

**Method** $\#2:$

Using De Moivre's formula,

$$\cos(2m+1)x+i\sin(2m+1)x=(\cos y+i\sin y)^{2m+1}=\cdots$$

Equating the imaginary parts (See [this](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/trigonometry/multipleAnglesSine.htm)),

$$\sin(2m+1)x=(2n+1)\sin x-\cdots+(-1)^{m-1}2^{2m-2}(2m+1)\sin^{2m-1}x+(-1)^m2^{2m}\sin^{2m+1}x$$

Now if $\sin(2m+1)x=0,(2m+1)x=r\pi$ where $r$ is any integer

$x=\dfrac{r\pi}{2m+1}$ where $r\equiv0,\pm1,\pm2,\cdots,\pm m\pmod{2m+1}$

Can you take it from here?