# Question regarding $f(n)=\cot^2\left(\frac\pi n\right)+\cot^2\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)+\cdots+\cot^2\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}n\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometry

$$f(n)=\cot^2\left(\frac\pi n\right)+\cot^2\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)+\cdots+\cot^2\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}n\right)$$ then how to find limit of $\dfrac{3f(n)}{(n+1)(n+2)}$ as $n\to\infty$?

I don't know any series like that. Riemann sum is not working. what to do?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951522/trig-sum-tan-21-circ-tan-22-circ-tan2-89-circ

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thanks.Seeing you after long time :-)!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Recall the expansion: $$\begin{align}\tan nx &= \dfrac{\binom{n}{1}\tan x - \binom{n}{3}\tan^3 x + \cdots }{1-\binom{n}{2}\tan^2 x + \binom{n}{4}\tan^4 x + \cdots } \\&= \frac{\binom{n}{1}\cot^{n-1} x - \binom{n}{3}\cot^{n-3} x + \cdots }{\cot^{n} x - \binom{n}{2}\cot^{n-2} x + \binom{n}{4}\cot^{n-4} x + \cdots }\end{align}$$

Now, $\displaystyle \left\{\frac{k\pi}{n}\right\}_{k=1}^{n-1}$ are the roots of the equation: $\displaystyle \tan nx = 0$

Thus, $\displaystyle \binom{n}{1}\cot^{n-1} x - \binom{n}{3}\cot^{n-3} x + \cdots = 0$ whenever, $x = \dfrac{k\pi}{n}$ for $1 \le k \le n-1$.

Thus, using Vieta's formula we might write:

$$\begin{align*}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \cot^2 \frac{k\pi}{n} &= \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \cot \frac{k\pi}{n}\right)^2 - 2\sum\limits_{1 \le k_1 < k_2 \le n-1} \cot \frac{k_1\pi}{n}\cot \frac{k_2\pi}{n}\\&= 0 + 2\frac{\binom{n}{3}}{\binom{n}{1}}\\&= \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{3}\end{align*}$$

Comment: Umm...could you tell me where you got the first formula?

Comment: Rest is great :-)!!

Comment: @SanchayanDutta It follows from applying De Moivre's formula, $\displaystyle \cos nx + i\sin nx = e^{inx} = (\cos x + i\sin x)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} i^{n-k} \binom{n}{k} \cos^k x \sin^{n-k} x = 0$ compare real and imaginary part on both sides.

Comment: This calculation is pivotal to [Cauchy's proof that $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#The_proof).