# Prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{1\leq k<j\leq n} \tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)\tan^2\left(\frac{j\pi}{2n+1}\right)=\binom{2n+1}{4} $

Tags: trigonometry, summation, binomial-coefficients

Prove that
$$\sum_{1\leq k < j\leq n}\tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)\tan^2\left(\frac{j\pi}{2n+1}\right)=\binom{2n+1}{4}$$

Comment: Where does this problem come from ? What have you attempted ?

Comment: It's nice identity, I have just detected it 

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217240/reference-for-a-tangent-squared-sum-identity . This identity can be proved by combining the sums for squares and fourth powers of tangents from this link http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Tan/23/01/

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562037/question-regarding-fn-cot2-left-frac-pi-n-right-cot2-left-frac2-pin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is enough to recall [Cauchy's proof of the Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), relying on the identity:

$$ \binom{2n+1}{1}t^n-\binom{2n+1}{3}t^{n-1}+\ldots+(-1)^n\binom{2n+1}{2n+1}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(t-\cot^2\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)\tag{1} $$
If we consider the "reciprocal polynomial"
$$ \binom{2n+1}{2n+1}t^n-\binom{2n+1}{2n-1}t^{n-1}+\ldots+(-1)^n\binom{2n+1}{1}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(t-\tan^2\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)\tag{2} $$
the original sum is just the second elementary symmetric polynomial of the roots, $e_2$, that by Vieta's theorem is given by the coefficient of $t^{n-2}$ in the LHS of $(2)$, so:
$$ \sum_{1\leq j<k\leq n}\tan^2\left(\frac{j\pi}{2n+1}\right)\tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)=\binom{2n+1}{2n-3}=\color{red}{\binom{2n+1}{4}}\tag{3}$$
as wanted.

Comment: Clair et net ! (the way I would have answered it). +1