# How to find the following sums.

Tags: trigonometry, summation

Let $$a=\sum  _{r=1}^{11}tan^2\bigg(\frac{r\pi}{24}\bigg) $$and $$b=\sum  _{r=1}^{11}(-1)^{r-1}tan^2\bigg(\frac{r\pi}{24}\bigg) $$
then find the value of $log_{(2b-a)}{(2a-b)}$.

---

In $a$ I find that $$tan^2\bigg(\frac{\pi}{24}\bigg)+tan^2\bigg(\frac{11\pi}{24}\bigg)=tan^2\bigg(\frac{\pi}{24}\bigg)+cot^2\bigg(\frac{\pi}{24}\bigg) =\frac{2}{sin^2\big(\frac{\pi}{12}\big)}-2$$
How do I use this to solve the problem ? How do I proceed further ?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951522/trig-sum-tan-21-circ-tan-22-circ-tan2-89-circ.  Btw what is the source of the problem