# Sum of tangent 1 to 89

Tags: trigonometry, summation

I was thinking of sum of tangent.
$$
\tan 1^∘+ \tan 2^∘ + ... + \tan 89^∘= ?
$$

I couldn't think of the answer of this.  Wolfram Alpha didn't says the exact form of this answer.

Comment: Are you sure that you have written down the problem correctly, and that it isn't $$\sum_{j=1}^{89} \tan(j)^2?$$

Comment: Since possibly the correct statement is as mentioned by @XanderHenderson here is the duplicated post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951522/trig-sum-tan-21-circ-tan-22-circ-tan2-89-circ?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: By Riemann sums such expression is close to $$-\frac{180}{\pi}\log\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{360}\right).$$ Its actual numerical value is $\approx 265.017371462$.