# Finding $\log_{2b – a}(2a – b)$, where $a=\sum_{r=1}^{11}\tan^2(\frac{r\pi}{24})$ and $b=\sum_{r=1}^{11}(-1)^{r-1}\tan^2(\frac{r\pi}{24})$

Tags: trigonometry

> Let $a = \sum\limits_{r = 1}^{11} {{{\tan }^2}\left( {\frac{{r\pi }}{{24}}} \right)} $ and $b = \sum\limits_{r = 1}^{11} {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{r - 1}}{{\tan }^2}\left( {\frac{{r\pi }}{{24}}} \right)} $, then find the value of $\log_{(2b – a)}(2a – b)$.

My approach to solve this is as follows: $\tan 2\theta  = \frac{{2\tan \theta }}{{1 - {{\tan }^2}\theta }} \Rightarrow 1 - \frac{{2\tan \theta }}{{\tan 2\theta }} = {\tan ^2}\theta.$

Comment: What is your question, then?  Clearly your approach doesn't solve it?

Comment: Using https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951522/trig-sum-tan-21-circ-tan-22-circ-cdots-tan2-89-circ-text, $$a=\dfrac{\binom{24}3}{\binom{24}1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some symmetries and trig identities help to simplify the sums.

The most important,

$$\cos{x+\pi}=-\cos{x}$$
$$\frac{1}{1+\cos{x}}+\frac{1}{1-\cos{x}}=\frac{4}{1-\cos{2x}}$$

Then:

$$a=\sum_{k=1}^{11}\tan^2{\frac{k\pi}{24}}=\sum_{k=1}^{11}(\sec^2{\frac{k\pi}{24}}-1)=-11+\sum_{k=1}^{11}\frac{2}{1+\cos{\frac{k\pi}{12}}}$$

$$2a=-22+2\sum_{k-1}^{11}(\frac{1}{1+\cos{\frac{k\pi}{12}}}+\frac{1}{1+\cos{\frac{(k+12)\pi}{12}}})=-22+2\sum_{k-1}^{11}(\frac{1}{1+\cos{\frac{k\pi}{12}}}+\frac{1}{1-\cos{\frac{k\pi}{12}}})$$

$$a=-11+4\sum_{k=1}^{11}\frac{1}{1-\cos{\frac{k\pi}{6}}}=-9+4\sum_{k=1}^{5}(\frac{1}{1-\cos{\frac{k\pi}{6}}}+\frac{1}{1-\cos{\frac{(k+6)\pi}{6}}})$$

$$a=-9+16\sum_{k=1}^{5}\frac{1}{1-\cos{\frac{k\pi}{3}}}$$

$$a=-1+16\sum_{k=1}^2\frac{2}{\sin^2{\frac{k\pi}{3}}}=-1+32(\frac{1}{3/4}+\frac{1}{3/4})=-1+256/3=253/3$$

So $a=253/3$.

Instead of calculating $b$, it's easier to calculate $a-b$. This cancels terms in the sum for odd values of $k$.

$$a-b=\sum_{k=1}^52(\sec^2{\frac{k\pi}{12}}-1)=-10+4\sum_{k=1}^5\frac{1}{1+\cos{\frac{k\pi}{6}}}$$

$$2(a-b)=-20+4\sum_{k=1}^5\frac{1}{1+\cos{k\pi/6}}+\frac{1}{1-\cos{k\pi/6}}=-20+16\sum_{k=1}^5\frac{1}{1-\cos{k\pi/3}}$$

$$a-b=-10+8\sum_{k=1}^5\frac{1}{1-\cos{k\pi/3}}$$

$a+9=2(a-b+10)\implies b=(a+11)/2=143/3$

Since $a=253/3$ and $b=143/3$,

$2a-b=(506-143)/3=121$

$2b-a=(286-253)/3=11$

ans: $\ln{121}/\ln{11}=2$

Comment: Can you please explain how you got $\frac{1}{1+\cos{\frac{k\pi}{12}}}+\frac{1}{1+\cos{\frac{(k+12)\pi}{12}}}$ from the previous result?

Comment: @Flagged. That's sort of a "reflection" about the line y=0. Instead of doubling by adding a perfect clone of the first part of that sum, the second part adds a sum with identical total because the cosines are the same.  by symmetry of the problem, if you only consider cosine, reflection through the plane and reflection through the origin are the same, as far as the total goes. Then this step allows applying one  of the previously  mentioned identities.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of my answer is to give you a series of hints and let you work out the exact calculations (I know, I'm lazy).

The main idea is that you can compute $a$ and $b$ by looking at these as the sums of roots of certain polynomials. As you know, the sum of the roots of a polynomial is [related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) to its constant coefficient.

Let $n=12$. For $a$ you need to compute
$$\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\tan^2\left(\frac {k\pi}{2n}\right) $$
So you'd like to find a polynomial whose roots are those squared tangents.

Start with $P(X)=(1+X)^{2n}-(1-X)^{2n}$.
Then any root $x$ of $P$ verifies $$(1+x)^{2n} = (1-x)^{2n}$$
or equivalently, $$\left( \frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^{2n} = 1$$
which means that the roots $x_r$ verify $\frac{1+x_r}{1-x_r}=e^{i\frac{r\pi}n}$ for $r=0,...,2n-1$. In other words, the roots of $P$ are
$$x_r=\frac{e^{i\frac{r\pi}n} - 1}{e^{i\frac{r\pi}n} + 1}=\frac{e^{i\frac{r\pi}{2n}}-e^{-i\frac{r\pi}{2n}}}{e^{i\frac{r\pi}{2n}} +e^{-i\frac{r\pi}{2n}}}=\tan \left(\frac {r\pi}{2n}\right)$$

Now the first sum, $a$, uses the squares of the tangents, so $P(X)$ is not quite what we need. But $P$ only has terms of even degree, so you can write $P(X) = Q(X^2)$, and the roots of $Q$ are, $$y_r = \tan^2\left(\frac {r\pi}{2n}\right)$$

So by looking at the constant coefficient for $Q$, you should be able to compute $a$.

As for $b$, you can notice that you can separate the sum into two sums (the terms for odd $r$'s, and the terms with even $r$'s). The sum with odd $r$'s has the same form as the one we had for $a$, except that you need to replace $n$ with $n/2$.

The second sum (even $r$'s) can be deduced from the first one (odd $r$'s) and $a$ itself.