# show that; strange sum yields triangular numbers $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\tan^2\left({k\pi\over 2n+1}\right)=T_{2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, trigonometry

$1,3,6,10,15,...$ for $n=1,2,3,...$ it is the n-th Triangular numbers.

I find it unsual that this sum yields even triangular numbers;

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\tan^2\left({k\pi\over 2n+1}\right)=T_{2n}$$

How can I show that? Any hints into this strange sum?

I can't figure it out where to start!

Comment: Huh, where did you find this?  :D  Interesting question!

Comment: Sorry I can't remember, I saw it in my note book. Probably wolfram site

Comment: It seems this question has been addressed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217240/reference-for-a-tangent-squared-sum-identity

Comment: Slight modification of arguments used in answers found here can be also used: [Prove that  $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\tan^{2}\frac{k \pi}{2n} = \frac{(n-1)(2n-1)}{3}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339/prove-that-sum-k-1n-1-tan2-frack-pi2n-fracn-12n-13)

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951522/trig-sum-tan-21-circ-tan-22-circ-tan2-89-circ  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610812/how-do-you-find-the-value-of-sum-r-044-tan22r1?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As recommended in the comment section of OPs question we can follow the nice answer of *[Fallager](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339/prove-that-sum-k-1n-1-tan2-frack-pi2n-fracn-12n-13/2343#2343)*.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\cos\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}+i\sin\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)^{2n+1}&=(-1)^k\tag{1}\\
> \\
> \sum_{j=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{j}\left(\cos\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)^j\left(i\sin \frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)^{2n+1-j}&=(-1)^k\tag{2}\\
> \\
> \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{2j}\left(\cos\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)^{2j}\left(i\sin \frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)^{2n+1-2j}&=0\tag{3}\\
> \\
> \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{2j}\left(i\tan \frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)^{2n+1-2j}&=0\tag{4}\\
> \\
> \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{2j}\left(i\tan \frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)^{2n-2j}&=0\tag{5}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use *[De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)*
- In (2) we apply the *[Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement)*
- In (3) we take the imaginary part of (2) i.e. with index $j$ even
- In (4) we divide by $\left(\cos \frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)^{2n+1}$
- In (5) we divide by $\tan \frac{k\pi}{2n+1}$

> We conclude $\left(\tan\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)^2$ with $0\leq k\leq 2n$ are the zeros of the following polynomial in $z$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{2j}\left(-z\right)^{n-j}
> \end{align*}
>
> According to *[Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Basic_formulas)* the sum of the zeros is
>   \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\tan\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)^2=\frac{\binom{2n+1}{2}}{\binom{2n+1}{0}}=n(2n+1)=T_{2n}
>   \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.